# Does Neutron Shark cause me to discard, even after destroying itself?

Tags: keyforge

If Neutron Shark destroys itself due to its own Play/Fight/Reap effect, how much more of its effect resolves? Does it just stop? Does it discard, then stop? Or can it even repeat after it’s destroyed?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You discard, but don’t repeat.
From Brad Andres (developer at FFG), via email:
“The effect will continue to resolve and the top card of their deck will be discarded, but no matter what card it hits the effect will not be able to resolve again because the card is no longer in play. Hope that helps.”

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted, but it would help if you specified why we should listen to Brad.

Comment: Can you please provide the source of your quote? Knowing where it is from will improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: Edited. If i notice it in a future FAQ entry, i’ll try to remember to come back and reference that instead.